# Using Swift and Firebase, how can I send an automated email to myself from an authenticated user of my app?

Tags: ios, swift, email, authentication

Can one of you kind people please point me in the right direction of what I need to research here?

For simplicity's sake, here's the gist of what I want to do:

Say there are two colours to choose from in an app and then a 'send' button. What I would like to do (in this example scenario) is have Firebase (or whatever else) send an email to a specified address (my own support address) when the user taps the 'send' button, where the content of the email is automated and states the user's email address (I already will have this through authentication), username, and the colour they selected.

What sort of thing can achieve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Look at [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com)

Comment: Thanks Ashley, I'll look into it! It's sounding so far like it's definitely a third party that needs to handle it, correct? Like, my app sends a request to the third party with the needed info, then that third party emails me? This'll be a lot of new learning! haha :P

Comment: Yeah - the only way to send emails using Apple's SDK is to use `MFMailComposeViewController`… there's no way to do it "silently". I've used SendGrid for a project of my own and found it pretty good. There's plenty of documentation and a great Swift library https://github.com/scottkawai/sendgrid-swift

Comment: Cool :) I've been studying it now for 2 days, and so I've registered on SendGrid and added the correct pod to my project and added the files from the git repository that you linked, but I'm not sure where to go from there or how to implement it. I know I have to set up an API key on SendGrid, but how do I connect my app to it? Do I have to 'import' something somewhere in my app to start accessing the SDK?

Comment: Nevermind, of course! I had to `import SendGrid` and then I was able to use `let session = Session()
        guard let myApiKey = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["SG_API_KEY"] else {
            print("Unable to retrieve API key")
            return
        }
        session.authentication = Authentication.apiKey(myApiKey)` ... Now just need to figure out the next step...

Answer (score 0):

I think that one clean way to do this is by HTTP request to your own backend server which implements a smtp service to send E-mail. By the way if you wish type some email from the iPhone, you should use MFMailComposeViewController(I think it's not for the scenario that you asking but...). It's quite simple.

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
{
        let composeVC: MFMailComposeViewController! = MFMailComposeViewController()

        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        composeVC.setToRecipients(["some_email@domain.com"])
        composeVC.setSubject("Some subject...")
        composeVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
        self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I read up on the MFMailComposeViewController(), but you're right, I'd be looking for something where the user wouldn't be explicitly aware of what's being sent. The actual scenario is when the user has an opportunity to choose a reward in my app, they simply choose what they want and then I get an email saying what they chose, and then I can email them back with details... I'll look into your first suggestion though, thanks!

Comment: My Pleasure brother. I already been on this situation before. For me was better build my own REST service for send email. You know, building out of the app on separate layer that you can maintain even though it is on AppStore. (Y)